# Compile C for PIC16F88 with sdcc

Tags: pic, linux

I'm trying to program my school learning board with PIC16F88 on Ubuntu. I installed sdcc and picpgm.

PIC16F88 already has bootloader so I intended to compile C code in to HEX with sdcc and then upload it with picpgm. We used microC's microBootloader tool in school.

So I tried to compile first and got to the first problem: when I call

```
$ sdcc -mpic16f88 lucke.c
```

I got:

```
at 1: error 131: cannot generate code for target 'pic16f88'
```

Did I think in the right direction at all? This is my first time with programming chips.

Comment: Where should I ask then?

Comment: Flagged for migration to StackOverflow.SE

Comment: @Andrej: Don't get discouraged by these comments, it is just the Stackexchange way of keeping questions organized.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-mpic16` at the command line.

Comment: Thanks, it is a step forward but I get errors: `lucke.c:25: warning 112: function 'Delay_ms' implicit declaration` and `lucke.c:25: error 101: too many parameters`

Comment: Entirely unrelated to this question. Register a new question and copy in the source code you are trying to compile.